# How to transfer audiobooks from linux pc to iOS?

Tags: ios, unix, data-transfer, audiobook, ibook

I want to transfer audiobook (as set of .mp3 files in one directory on my PC) to iBooks on for example iPad. Idea is to listen that particular audiobook on iPad with help of iBooks.

How can I do that?

Comment: I was going to suggest running a web server with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` and downloading the files with Safari but that didn't work: the files play but can't be saved. I have successfully done that to transfer images, pdfs, epubs, but I hadn't tried mp3 before now.